# How do I properly order NTFS ACL using icacls?

Tags: access-control-list, ntfs, icacls

I have a directory structure 4 subdirectories deep:  [Department] -> [Job #] -> [Docs] -> [EMail]

At the [Docs] level I have 4 groups inherited from root and one group (st_JobDocs) explicit.  All inherit to subfolders.

```
st_JobAdmin: grant F
st_Job_R: grant RX
st_JobDocs: grant F
st_ITStorageAdmin: grant F
st_GlobalDeny: deny F
```

At level [Email] I want to remove st_JobDocs and st_Job_R groups; keep st_GlobalDeny, st_ITStorageAdmin, and st_JobAdmin; and add st_JobDocsEmail:(OI)(CI)(F).

To do that I run from the [Department] level:

```
for /D %%D in (*) do for /D %%F in (%%D\Docs) do icacls "%%F\E-Mail" /inheritance:d
for /D %%D in (*) do for /D %%F in (%%D\Docs) do icacls "%%F\E-Mail" /remove:g "st_Job_R"
for /D %%D in (*) do for /D %%F in (%%D\Docs) do icacls "%%F\E-Mail" /remove:g "st_JobDocs"
for /D %%D in (*) do for /D %%F in (%%D\Docs) do icacls "%%F\E-Mail" /remove:d "st_GlobalDeny""
for /D %%D in (*) do for /D %%F in (%%D\Docs) do icacls "%%F\E-Mail" /grant:r "st_JobDocsEmail":(OI)(CI)(F)
for /D %%D in (*) do for /D %%F in (%%D\Docs) do icacls "%%F\E-Mail" /deny "st_GlobalDeny":(OI)(CI)(F)
```

I thought by removing st_GlobalDeny and adding it at the end I would maintain compliance with permission precedence: Explicit Deny, Allow, Inherited Deny, Allow.  But for some reason when I check the security tab of one of the folders I get the error:

> The permission on [dir] are incorrectly ordered, which may cause some
>   entries to be ineffective.

Can someone help me understand the ordering and why mine is incorrect?  Also, is there a command line tool that will correct the order?

As a side question, is it possible to remove only the inheritance on one group instead of all with icacls and /inheritance:d?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Windows?  I'm thinking your best bet is to do everything on one command line (you can include multiple options at once) and use `/inheritance:r` but try it out in a test environment first, if you lock yourself out by mistake it can be difficult to recover from.

Comment: Also, what does `icacls` show for one of the broken folders?

Comment: @Harry icacls is showing my st_GlobalDeny twice.  Odd. 
 Once at the top of the list and than once in the middle.  Obviously why I am getting the error.  Almost like my /remove:d st_GlobalDeny isn't working.  When I reorder from the security tab the st_GlobalDeny in the middle is removed.  As for inheritance:r, so you think remove everything and then readd everything?  I hadn't tried that because I was afraid I'd lose access.  I will try.  Thank you!  I'll get back with updates when I have them.

Comment: I feel stupid. :(  After bringing up my script in notepad I used the horizontal scroll bar and noticed a second quote at the end of my /remove:d line that was being hidden off the page.  Sorry to bother you all.

Answer (score 0):

Global Deny is not being removed.  In the script example on the /remove:d "st_GlobalDeny" line there is an extra quotation mark at the end.